# How to bind data to label in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want bind the data to label control at controller level. i have a main Tab-Panel view within view have two more view like example1 view and specification view. in specification tab view have a label is id: `lblSpecification`, for this label i am going to bind data at controller level as shown below. But it is not working. 
controller code is here:

```
config: {
  refs: {
    specificationPage: "specification",
    specificationLabel: "#lblSpecification"
  },

  control: {
    specificationPage: {
      initialize: "SpecificationInitialize"
    }
  },

  SpecificatiTabInitialize: function () {
    this.getSpecificationLabel().setHtml("Welcome");
  }
}
```

I have created another similar project, where I am not using tab panel, I have followed similar steps as code mentioned above, its working fine, please can I know its the problem due to tabpanel or is their any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you check whether the control is at all going to the "SpecificatiTabInitialize" function or not? Put a console.log() there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to setHtml when label is initialized but not a panel.